# Unable to boot DD'd Windows 10 drive

Tags: windows, boot, dd

NOTE: Already posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657563/unable-to-boot-ddd-windows-10-drive . After no activity there for almost 5 days, and no option I have used in the past to move between subsites, posting here as well. Hopefully both can exist, but if not maybe better here.

Booted into SystemRescueCD and with a USB to SATA adaptor attached to the PC issued the command `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress`. A few hours later I had what looked from partitions shown in Linux's `fdisk` to be an exact duplicate of the original drive. However when selecting this drive, still connected to the PC via the USB to SATA adaptor, in BIOS as the first boot device when the boot process gets to the stage an OS is launched the screen gets stuck for presumably ever on a blank screen with a flashing cursor top left. The original HDD booted before and after this test with compatible UEFI turned on and secure boot turned off (as was set when DD was used).

Have read elsewhere that the system reserved partition needs to be marked as active, but this seems to only apply to MBR boot sectors according to Windows' `diskpart`. Also that `bcdboot <windows location> /s <drive with bcd to repair>` needs to be run, but that didn't change the symptoms when done.

Find below screenshot of the partitions and status for the original HDD first (Disk 0), and then the copy second (Disk 1).

What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged. [Consider deleting the other copy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/355310). One of the reasons to close a question on U&L SE is cross-posting, so if you don't delete it then the community may delete it anyway. I'm the first who voted to delete the copy on U&L. Nothing personal, just maintenance.

Comment: (1) When you tried to boot, was the original and the copy connected at the same time? Identical signatures of partitions and filesystems are not a good thing. (2) Have you tried to connect the copy in place of the original? So all the other hardware is the same and the original is disconnected. Then boot. What happens?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Not for you, but others, I addressed why it would be good for both to stay on the U&L posting mentioned. As an aside, SE really needs to consider a way to address a question that transects two or more of their subsites, given the rule about cross posting.

Comment: Windows has trouble booting from USB disks and it is not supported. Connect the disk in place of your current disk, i.e. via SATA and try again.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski As to your questions, (1) I tried booting it on the same PC first (not sure why BIOS would be even reading the boot sector of a device it isn't booting, but I am sure if I had problems with an indication Windows had gotten to the stage of loading other storage devices that would be a good explanation), and also on a separate PC with non identical hardware (I would assume I would at least get the Windows logo before it hit a driver it couldn't load) with no joy there either. (2) I cannot given PC has a NVMe SSD and no SATA ports I can see.

Comment: @Mokubai - I can only connect the HDD to a different PC given the laptop that the image came from only has a NVMe SSD, and no SATA ports. In the past though I have gotten the Windows logo for a short period of time before presumably some base level driver couldn't be found for crucial hardware and the screen freezes. If I am not seeing the WIndows logo at all I thought that to be an indication of a boot loader issue. Could I ask if you know where I can go to see boot logs to see if Windows is even starting on the copy HDD?

Comment: @user66001 - Even if your question is answered here, it will result in your question at U&L to be closed, since it should be migrated and closed as a duplicate of a question here.  Which is difficult for all the reviewers to accomplish.

Comment: @Ramhound The goal is an answered question, so that wouldn't be an issue for me. It wouldn't be posted in both places if this doesn't relate to Linux and Windows.